# Including SVG into LaTeX

Tags: pdf, svg, latex

I want to include a svg file in a LaTeX document.

## a.svg (given)

[image: given.svg]

## a.pdf (goal)

[image: goal.pdf]
I created the table with OpenOffice, exported it to a pdf-file, imported it into inkscape afterwards and saved it as an svg file.

## What I have tried

### Include svg directly

I tried to include the given svg file directly using the [svg package](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/graphics/svg/svg.pdf):

```
\usepackage{svg}
...
\includesvg{img/a}
```

But it did not compile, because pdflatex did not found the file a. I also tried a.svg but without any success :(

### Exporting to pdf "on the fly"

Following [J. Engelen](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) I tried to generate the pdf file using pdflatex with  -enable-write18 or --shell-escape but it didn't do anything with the .svg file except throwing an error, that the .pdf_tex file is missing.

### Export to pdf / pdf_tex before including

I exported the svg file using inkscape v. 0.92:

> inkscape -D -z --file=a.svg --export-pdf=a.pdf --export-latex

I got a .pdf file containing the blank table:
[image: raw pdf file]
And a .pdf_tex file containing the following:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.1, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'RLE1.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{608.85768187bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.13941476)%
    \put(0.12815803,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{352}}}%
    \put(0.18117534,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{320}}}%
    \put(0.23419265,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{288}}}%
    \put(0.28720997,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{256}}}%
    \put(0.34027656,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{224}}}%
    \put(0.39329387,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{192}}}%
    \put(0.44631119,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{160}}}%
    \put(0.4993285,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{128}}}%
    \put(0.56160906,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{96}}}%
    \put(0.61462638,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{64}}}%
    \put(0.66767654,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{32}}}%
    \put(0.7299571,0.12595718){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0}}}%
    \put(0.12007732,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.17309463,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.22611195,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x3}}}%
    \put(0.27912926,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x2}}}%
    \put(0.33214658,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x2}}}%
    \put(0.38521317,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.43823048,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.49124779,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.54426511,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.59728242,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.65033259,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.7033499,0.10191216){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.39329387,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{192}}}%
    \put(0.44631119,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{160}}}%
    \put(0.4993285,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{128}}}%
    \put(0.56160906,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{96}}}%
    \put(0.61462638,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{64}}}%
    \put(0.66767654,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{32}}}%
    \put(0.7299571,0.03056543){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0}}}%
    \put(0.33214658,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{0}\textit{x}\textit{2}}}}%
    \put(0.38521317,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.43823048,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{0}\textit{x}\textit{1}}}}%
    \put(0.49124779,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x3}}}%
    \put(0.54426511,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{0}\textit{x}\textit{2}}}}%
    \put(0.59728242,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x2}}}%
    \put(0.65033259,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\textit{0}\textit{x}\textit{7}}}}%
    \put(0.7033499,0.00652041){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{0x1}}}%
    \put(0.04755463,0.10270052){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{…}}}%
    \put(0.15358269,0.00730877){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{…}}}%
    \put(0.82929066,0.10210925){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{unkomprimierte Daten}}}%
    \put(0.90260828,0.05441337){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{RleCompress}}}%
    \put(0.84821134,0.0067175){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{komprimierte Daten}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=44]{img/a.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

I used this file within LaTeX like the following:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\textwidth}
    \input{a.pdf_tex}    
\end{figure}
```

The resulting .pdf file from my LaTeX file looks like that:
[image: result.pdf]

As one can see, the italic font style is everything, inkscape exported. 
The font color is not exported at all.

The LaTeX font size of the index values should be `\tiny`.
Of course I can change the font style manually, but this does not seem like a proper way to me.

Also, the boxes around the index values behave like the following, when I try to resize them using `\tiny`:
[image: Strange box alignment]

Does anyone knows, how to proper import svg files, containing text into a LaTeX document while preserving all the font styles and colors and of course the positioning?

Sincerely

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex and should be asked on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange site. It is not primarily about programming, but about using LaTeX.

Answer (score 10):

I realize that this thread is 4 + years old but since I found my way here maybe someone else will.

The syntax `inkscape -D -z` etc. is deprecated for newer versions of Inkscape, and has been replaced with:

```
inkscape --export-filename=yourpdfoutput.pdf yoursvginput.svg
```

See the man-page or their online documentation https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Strange, the approach you used works perfectly for me, however I get a different pdf_tex file from conversion.

**b.pdf_tex**

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.1, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'b.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
   \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{798bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.23026316)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{b.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \input{b.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image: working example]

My Inkscape version is

Inkscape 0.92.1 r

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.2.2

Comment: This is quite strange, isn't it? My setup is: 

Inkscape 0.92.1 unknown

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)

Comment: Die you perform some kind of postprocessing within Inkscape? Like setting anchorpoints for the text?

Comment: And how did you generate the table? The same way like me: openoffice -> pdf -> inkscape -> svg -> inkscape -> pdf/pdf_tex
Or did you use something like the table_extension within inkscape?

Comment: I just downloaded the pic you uploaded, opened it in Inkscape, then saved it as svg and converted with the above command. Nothing special or fancy